# Creating a new data frame from an existing data frame based on a condition (for loops, Python)

Tags: python

I have a data frame (data) with columns such as net sales, product, vendor etc. I would have to create sub-data frames from this main_data table per each vendor. Lets say that there are 5 unique vendors (vendor1, vendor2, vendor3, vendor4 and vendor5) in the data table vendor column. I would have to create 5 different sub-data frames for each of these vendors. The sub-data frames should contain all data from the main table, but filtered for vendorX.

How would I do this by using for loops?

Comment: Don't use a `for` loop, use pandas [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) method.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pandas, you can do:

```
df_v1 = main_data[main_data['vendor'] =='vendor1']
```

Comment: Hi, yes but due to my further actions, I would have to create these sub data frames by using for loops. Any idea of how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say below is your dataFrame:
[image]

As it can be seen in above image, there are 5 vendors(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5)

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#importing dataFrame from dump excel
df = pd.read_excel('stack.xlsx')

dfList  = list(set(df['vendor'])) 


dfNames = ["df" + row for row in dfList] 

for i, row in enumerate(dfList):
    dfName = dfNames[i]
    dfNew = df[df['vendor'] == row]
    globals()[dfName] = dfNew
    print(globals()[dfName])
    print('------------------------------------------') 

#from above for loop there will be 5 dataFrames generated as dfv1, dfv3, dfv5, dfv4, dfv2. You can use these all dataFrames now
```

**Output:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'product': ['P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4', 'P5', 'P6', 'P7'], 
        'vendor': ['vendor1','vendor2','vendor2','vendor1','vendor3', 'vendor2', 'vendor3'] }
main_data = pd.DataFrame(data)

print('Original dataframe:')
print(main_data)
print('-----')

#this will store key value pairs of vendorX, sub_dataframe for vendorX
by_vendor = dict()
for vendorX in main_data.vendor.unique():
    maskX = main_data['vendor'] == vendorX
    by_vendor[vendorX] = main_data[maskX]

for vendorX, sub_data in by_vendor.items():
    print('subdataframes for vendor ', vendorX)
    print(sub_data)
    print('-----')
```

This is the output:

```
Original dataframe:
  product   vendor
0      P1  vendor1
1      P2  vendor2
2      P3  vendor2
3      P4  vendor1
4      P5  vendor3
5      P6  vendor2
6      P7  vendor3
-----
subdataframe for vendor  vendor1
  product   vendor
0      P1  vendor1
3      P4  vendor1
-----
subdataframe for vendor  vendor2
  product   vendor
1      P2  vendor2
2      P3  vendor2
5      P6  vendor2
-----
subdataframe for vendor  vendor3
  product   vendor
4      P5  vendor3
6      P7  vendor3
-----
```

Note that the output has three vendors in this case, but would have more if `main_data` had more of them. This code can handle any number of unique vendors.

Here, the answer is stored in a dictionary named `by_vendor`, which stores `sub_data` dataframe for `vendorX`, which can be accessed by `by_vendor[vendorX]` (`by_vendor['vendor1']`, `by_vendor['vendor2']`, etc).

The line `for vendorX in main_data.vendor.unique():` iterates over all the unique entries present in the vendor column. For each unique vendor `vendorX`, we do the following:

`maskX` is a series containg a `True`/`False` value for each row, depending on whether the vendor for that row equals `vendorX` or not.

We use this maskX with [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) to create `sub_data` dataframe for `vendorX`.

The left hand side of the expression is simply assigning the `sub_data` belonging to `vendorX` in a dictionary with key `vendorX`.

The two statements can be combined into a single one: `by_vendor[vendorX] = main_data[main_data['vendor'] == vendorX]`

You can ditch the `by_vendor` dictionary and still use boolean indexing to manually put values into five variables named vendorX if you'd like, I found this method to be more elegant as it can be applied to any case.